# FFMPEG with QT memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, qt4, ffmpeg, libavcodec

Let me start with a code clip:

```
QByteArray ba;
ba.resize(500000);

int encsize = avcodec_encode_video(context, (uint8_t*)ba.data(), 500000, frame.unownedPointer());
```

What I'm doing is encoding the data from frame and putting the data into the buffer pointed at QByteArray. If I comment out the avcodec_encode_video line my memory leak goes away. unownedPointer() looks like this:

```
 if (this->frame != NULL) return this->frame;
    this->frame =  avcodec_alloc_frame();
    uchar *data = this->img.bits();
    frame->data[0] = (uint8_t *)data;
    frame->data[1] = (uint8_t *)data + 1;
    frame->data[2] = (uint8_t *)data + 2;
    frame->linesize[0] = width * lineSize(this->fmt);
    frame->linesize[1] = width * lineSize(this->fmt);
    frame->linesize[2] = width * lineSize(this->fmt);
    return this->frame;
```

Where this->frame is a AVFrame *, and this->img is a QImage.

At a encoding rate of about 30fps, I'm getting a memory leak of about 50MB/sec. So I'm not sure what the issue could be. It seems as if avcodec_encode_video() is copying memory and never freeing it or something. Any ideas?

If avcodec_encode_video is converting my RGB24 data to YUV420P would it be modifying the data pointed to by frame.unownedPointer()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code for [QtFFmpegwrapper](http://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/) it uses a saved context to do this efficently, or you can just use the QtFFMpegwrapper directly

Comment: Completely unusable in my situation. It only supports reading/writing to a file, plus this doesn't answer what is causing the memory leak.

Comment: After looking at it again, it appears it might work...I'd have to heavily edit some code though,  to get that to happen.

Comment: Sorry - can't see whats wrong with your code, it depends on how ffmpeg manages the memory. Just thought I would point out an alternative - you can use the exampel in their about how to call swscale to do RGB->YUV conversion, there is also a sample of the direct RGB->YUV fucntion